# How to scale datasets correctly

Tags: python, machine-learning

Which one is more correct or there is any other way to scale data?  (I've used `StandardScaler` as an example)
I've tried every way and computed the accuracy of every model but there is no meaningful difference but I want to know which way is more correct

```
dataset= pd.read_csv("wine.csv")

x = dataset.iloc[:,:13]
y = dataset.iloc[:,13]

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.8,random_state=0)

sc=StandardScaler()

x_train=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=sc.fit_transform(x_test)
```

**or**

```
dataset= pd.read_csv("wine.csv")

x = dataset.iloc[:,:13]
y = dataset.iloc[:,13]

sc=StandardScaler()

x = sc.fit_transform(x)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.8,random_state=0)
```

**or**

```
dataset= pd.read_csv("wine.csv")

x = dataset.iloc[:,:13]
y = dataset.iloc[:,13]

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.8,random_state=0)

sc=StandardScaler()

x_train=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=sc.transform(x_test)
```

Comment: The last one. See e.g. answers here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39932/feature-scaling-both-training-and-test-data

Comment: 100% sure the last one is the way to go.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data should not bee seen or used during the training a of model as they are used to assert the performance of the model.

Therefore the last option is the correct one. The scaling parameter should be computed solely on the train set as follow:

```
sc=StandardScaler()
x_train=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=sc.transform(x_test)
```